# transfer function for speed control of bldc motor using PI controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

can anyone tell me the transfer function for speed control of bldc motor using PI controller

Comment: No we can't son.

Comment: It's G(s) . . .

Comment: is it possible to calculate by knowing the TF of each block that i used?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way.

Comment: pls tell me the TF of a BLDC motor

Comment: i need a bode plot .is ther any direct way using MATLAB SIMULINK

Comment: https://au.mathworks.com/help/control/getstart/linear-lti-models.html#f1-1010945

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not going to give away the answer, that would deprive you of learning. 
But I will explain what is going on.
So here is the basic model of your control loop:

[image]

Your controller model is

$$H(s)= K_1 + K_2/s$$

Your plant (or motor) model \$ G(s) \$ is going to be dependent on the motor controller and the motor, if you have an actual motor and controller you could do a system id to find the frequency response.

The other thing you will need to do is find the frequency response of the sensor (encoder, hall effect ect) that senses speed or position if you have one.

Once the frequency response or transfer function for all of the components of the control system is found you can use the diagram and equations below to combine them. 
Keep in mind that in the diagram below \$ G(s) \$ will also be combined with the controller \$ G(s)_{bottom}= H(s)_{top}*G(s)_{top} \$ (top is the diagram above)

[image]